# Blank white screen while pixel drawing using FreeGLUT and CUDA?

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-c++, cuda, freeglut

I'am out of ideas what is going on.
Only i know, that freeglut is discarding my code for reasons i don't know.
I initializing it:

```
glutInit(argc, args);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
glutInitWindowSize(wnd_width, wnd_height);
glutDisplayFunc(_display);
glutTimerFunc(16, tick, 0);
glutCreateWindow(appName);
glutCloseFunc(close);
glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) return 2;
glGenBuffersARB(1, &_PBO);
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, _PBO);
glBufferDataARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, wnd_width*wnd_height*sizeof(GLubyte)* 4, 0, GL_STREAM_DRAW_ARB);
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, 0);
cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&PBOCUDA, _PBO, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsWriteDiscard);
unsigned int size = wnd_width * wnd_width * 4 * sizeof(float);
glutMainLoop();
```

Then i drawing it in two functions:

```
++timeVar;
cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &PBOCUDA, 0);
size_t num_bytes;
cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void **)&d_output, &num_bytes, PBOCUDA);
cudaTestWork1(timeVar, d_output, wnd_width, wnd_height);
cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &PBOCUDA, 0);
display(wnd_width, wnd_height, _PBO);
```

And display():

```
glClearColor(0.3f,0.3f,0.3f,0.3f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glRasterPos2i(0, 0);
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, img);
glDrawPixels(x, y, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, 0);
glutSwapBuffers();
```

It isn't react even on glClearColor, it is just white. I can resize the window, and if I make it bigger the black field is appering, if i make it smaller the white color will be erased. I tried to find why is it just white and nothing happens, but there is only a vertex drawing problems, the solution for them is set up projectiong matrix.

**Why it is giving me a blank white screen?**

P.S. CUDA code is working, I have experience with it, so it must work fine. 
And I almost copy-pasted it from project where it works. I'd checked everything, but all is perfect, i even copied a libs, so it is same projects but with different code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the most stupid mistake i've ever seen. I missed the order!

I just made glut init like this:

```
glutInit(argc, args);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
glutInitWindowSize(wnd_width, wnd_height);
glutCreateWindow(appName); // goes first
glutDisplayFunc(_display); // then functions
glutCloseFunc(close);
glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
```

and NOW it works! We need to firstly create a window and THEN apply functions to it. And in display() i added glutPostRedisplay() to let glut redraw after it is done (when it reaches this point).

So now display() looks like this:

```
glClearColor(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glRasterPos2i(0, 0);
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, img);
glDrawPixels(x, y, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, 0);
glutSwapBuffers();
glutPostRedisplay();
```

And yeah as i said in question my CUDA code is works... at least somehow...